# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in "location" Stack trace: #0

Tags: php, html, mysql, registration

I'm sorry for asking something that might be entirely obvious. I'm getting a fatal error, but nothing seems to be the problem because everything seems to be working. (The user gets registred)

I'm currently learning PHP and I'm learning it by editing existing code. So this is not my code from the beginning. Anyway, this code worked perfectly last week. I have no memory of actually editing it. Now when I'm testing it, it gives me a fatal error (the one in the title). It's complaining about the code "register.php(50): PDOStatement->fetchAll() #1"

the code is:

```
<?php


include('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
 header("location:index.php");
}

$message = '';

if(isset($_POST["register"]))
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM users 
 WHERE user_email = :user_email
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':user_email' => $_POST['user_email']
  )
 );
 $no_of_row = $statement->rowCount();
 if($no_of_row > 0)
 {
  $message = '<label class="text-danger">Email Already Exits</label>';
 }
 else
 {
  $user_password = rand(100000,999999);
  $user_encrypted_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $user_activation_code = md5(rand());
  $insert_query = "
  INSERT INTO users
  (user_name, user_email, user_password, user_activation_code, user_email_status) 
  VALUES (:user_name, :user_email, :user_password, :user_activation_code, :user_email_status)
  ";
  $statement = $connect->prepare($insert_query);
  $statement->execute(
   array(
    ':user_name'   => $_POST['user_name'],
    ':user_email'   => $_POST['user_email'],
    ':user_password'  => $user_encrypted_password,
    ':user_activation_code' => $user_activation_code,
    ':user_email_status' => 'not verified'
   )
  );
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
  if(isset($result))
  {
```

I'm trying to see the problem but I can't. I would appreciate if someone could find the issue.. After the if isset code, there is just a phpmailer function.

I know that I'm not good but I'm trying to learn and would like to know where I messed up. Thanks

Comment: You can't fetch after an insert.

Comment: But it worked last week without errors? even the main code tells me that it should be like that..